# Download input images with vue.js

Tags: windows, vue.js

So the images are saved when I try to save them with this

```
transferFiles(){
       this.checkMark = true
   let i = 0
    this.finalImages.forEach((image) =>{
       i++
       saveAs(image, "imagem.jpg"+i);
    })
   }
```

this is the error:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 ReferenceError: saveAs is not defined
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/SelectImagesSection.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:424)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at VueComponent.transferFiles (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/SelectImagesSection.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:422)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:1853)
    at HTMLInputElement.invoker (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:2178)
    at HTMLInputElement.original._wrapper (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:6907)
logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888
```

Basically, all images are saved but can t f
it says that the saveAS is not defined

Comment: First please update your image name on saving. You shouldn't add your iterator on the file extension. It will result in invalid file names, example: `imagem.jpg3`. Replace that line with this one: `saveAs(image, \`imagem-${i}.jpg\`);`

Comment: where do you define your `saveAs` function?

Comment: @transGLUKator i only use saveAS there

Comment: @maki000 going to change

Comment: to be able to use a function you need to define it first. the error states exactly that. `saveAs` function is not a part of browser API so you either need to define it yourself or import it from a library

Comment: @transGLUKator I imported it from file saver but still gives me wrong

Comment: can you then update your post with how exactly you import `saveAs` function

Comment: @transGLUKator like this but in another file: import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

Comment: you should import saveAs in the same file that uses it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just need to import and install file saver function
import  saveAs  from 'file-saver';